# efficient cumulative pivot in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is there a more efficient/idiomatic way of rewriting this query:

```
spark.table('registry_data')
    .withColumn('age_days', datediff(lit(today), col('date')))
    .withColumn('timeframe', 
               when(col('age_days')<7, "1w")
              .when(col('age_days')<30, '1m')
              .when(col('age_days')<92, '3m')
              .when(col('age_days')<183, '6m')
              .when(col('age_days')<365, '1y')
              .otherwise('1y+')
    )
   .groupby('make', 'model')
      .pivot('timeframe')
         .agg(countDistinct('id').alias('count'))
         .fillna(0)
  .withColumn('1y+', col('1y+')+col('1y')+col('6m')+col('3m')+col('1m')+col('1w'))
  .withColumn('1y', col('1y')+col('6m')+col('3m')+col('1m')+col('1w'))
  .withColumn('6m', col('6m')+col('3m')+col('1m')+col('1w'))
  .withColumn('3m', col('3m')+col('1m')+col('1w'))
  .withColumn('1m', col('1m')+col('1w'))
```

The gist of the query is for every make/model combination to return the number of entries seen within a set of time periods from today.  The period counts are cumulative, i.e. an entry that registered within the last 7 days would be counted for 1 week, 1 month, 3 months, etc.

Comment: Input and desirable data output samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use cumulative sum instead of summing for each columns, you can replace the code from `.groupby` onwards and use window functions

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark.table('registry_data')
    .withColumn('age_days', datediff(lit(today), col('date')))
    .withColumn('timeframe', 
               when(col('age_days')<7, "1w")
              .when(col('age_days')<30, '1m')
              .when(col('age_days')<92, '3m')
              .when(col('age_days')<183, '6m')
              .when(col('age_days')<365, '1y')
              .otherwise('1y+')
    )
   .groupBy('make', 'model', 'timeframe')
   .agg(F.countDistinct('id').alias('count'), 
        F.max('age_days').alias('max_days')) # for orderBy clause
   .withColumn('cumsum', 
                F.sum('count').over(Window.partitionBy('make', 'model')
                              .orderBy('max_days')
                              .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)))
   .groupBy('make', 'model').pivot('timeframe').agg(F.first('cumsum'))
   .fillna(0)
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Window functions isn't something my brain goes to on its own